# Wondering if my probability proof is enough or if there is more that can be done.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

my task was to prove the following or provide a counterexample:

If $P(A \mid C) > P(A \mid C^c)$ and $P(B \mid C) > P(B \mid C^c)$ then $P(AB \mid C) > P(AB \mid C^c)$.

My proof is as follows:

\begin{align*}
P(AB \mid C) > P(AB \mid C^c) & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{P(ABC)}{P(C)} > \frac{P(ABC^c)}{P(C^c)} \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{P(CAB)}{P(C)} > \frac{P(C^cAB)}{P(C^c)} \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{P(C)P(A \mid C) P(B \mid AC)}{P(C)} > \frac{P(C^c) P(A \mid C^c) P(B \mid AC^c)}{P(C^c)} \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow P(A \mid C)P(B \mid AC) > P(A \mid C^c) P(B \mid AC^c)) \\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow P(B \mid AC) > P(B \mid AC^c)
\end{align*}

I feel like this is enough to prove it because obviously the above would be true because it's known that $P(B \mid C) > P(B \mid C^c)$ and $P(A \mid C) > P(A \mid C^c)$. Is there a better way for me to explain this? I also understand I may be totally wrong. Thank you!

Edit: Fixed my \LaTeX

Comment: I would try to construct a counter-example.  You can do this by defining any joint probability distribution over $A,B,C$ that you like.

Comment: @ted Thank you! I've tried this doing A = event that ace is pulled first, B = event that ace is pulled third, and C = event that ace is pulled second. Then found $P(B \mid AC) = \frac{2}{50}$ and $P(B \mid A C^c) = \frac{3}{50}$. So I showed contradiction to my proof, would this be enough?

Comment: Hint: construct events such that $P(AB|C)=0$ and $P(AB|C^c)\neq 0$ that satisfies the other constraints

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the statement you are being asked to prove or disprove is true.  You can construct any joint distribution over $\{A,B,C\}$ that you like. So just construct one that breaks the claim.

You don't need to resort to card games, dice, or other real world scenarios. To define a joint distribution over 3 variables, just make a table like the one below and add probabilities in the last column on the right that sum to one.

Entries with a value of "0" mean that variable is false for that row (i.e., the complement is true). And entries with a value of "1" mean that the variable is true for that row.

| A | B | C | P(A,B,C) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | *insert your joint probability for this outcome here |

More info on joint probability tables can be [found here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-calculate-joint-marginal-and-conditional-probability/)